# Did I rigged the fingers right?

Tags: modeling, rigging, unity, pose-mode

I'm new to making an armature of fingers. I usually don't know if I rigged it right. Here's one of my screenshots
[image]

The index finger bones were "Keep Offset" to the Hand bone which is not connected but they were related to it.

Now my problem here is that I tried importing it on Unity while changing its Animation Type from Generic to Humanoid I tried applying it and there's an error on this area which the Finger14.L is not an ancestor of Finger02.L I tried looking at it at first it was typo error but then it's like a serious problem that those finger bones weren't connected to each other. How do I fix it.

(Revised)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 5 more bones, each connecting (connected) the hand to each palm finger bone.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks I'll do it, I'll comment again if anything happens.

Comment: Thanks! I surely did connect the bones to the palm and as I import it to Unity no issues have been detected.

Comment: Glad to hear, if it's been useful please mark the answer as accepted.